# selenium session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist, then becomes timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

selenium 4.18.1
chromedriver-122.0.6261.69-1.fc39.x86_64
google-chrome-stable-122.0.6261.94-1.x86_64

using this driver invocation

```
wdoptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
wdoptions.add_argument('disable-gpu')
wdoptions.add_argument('window-size=1440,2400')    
webdriver.Chrome(options=wdoptions)
```

After a 10 hours of usage, I started getting this error:

```
session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

In SO posts, I saw to try

```
wdoptions.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
```

However after the same 10hours of usage (actually the exact same, on the next day), I see this error

```
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000
```

I do call driver.quit() if I'm gonna be idle for more than 5mns, and then create a new driver to start a new session.

Any ideas?
Rds,

Comment: question asked here as well https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4403